# How to recover glibc?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm running Arch Linux. Today i have tried to update my system, there was an error when trying to update "glibc" package. I don't remember correctly what was the error message (something about "/usr/lib/modules" moved to "/lib/modules"). Now, i know that "glibc" is VERY important for the system, but i just wanted to try something crazy - install new "glibc" after i delete the old one with "sudo pacman -Rnn glibc". It turned out to be VERY bad idea, after removing old "glibc" my system can't recognize "sudo", "dir" and other commands so i can't install new "glibc".
Can you suggest me some solution? How to get out of this situation? :)

Comment: In the future, please PLEASE read the archlinux news before updating. http://www.archlinux.org/news/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

glibc (or some other C library) is required for virtually everything in a Linux system. Removing it is a Really Bad Idea, as you've discovered the hard way.

The easiest way to recover from this is to boot from the Arch Linux CD and reinstall glibc to your system. [One possible way to do this is provided on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/When_LIBC_Is_Broken).

Comment: How could i do it? Can you give me some tutorial please?

Comment: I hate to say this, but if you don't know at least the basics of using a Linux system, then you probably shouldn't be running Arch. If you really want to continue, you should read the [Official Arch Linux Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Official_Installation_Guide#Select_Packages) and [When LIBC Is Broken](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/When_LIBC_Is_Broken) (which I just found).

Comment: I just came here to accept your answer and then saw your comment. Yes, yes i followed wiki page, re installed glibc (mounted live cd, then mounted hdd with broken Arch, install glibc using "pacman -S glibc --root /mnt/brokenRoot") and it worked :) I had no idea how to do it cause i never HAD to do it so i never had any interest in methods of recovering from things like this ;) I tend to learn things the hard way, BUT when i learn something that way, it lasts forever :) Otherwise, it's just "too much information for "just in case""